# Dojo fails to load from google's CDN using Chrome; produces Uncaught illegal access

Tags: dojo, cdn

When I load dojo 1.4 from google's CDN, I get the following error:

native string.js:183 Uncaught illegal access

This only happens on about half the refreshes when using Chrome, other times it works fine. I've verified that the problem reproduces on multiple windows machines running Chrome.

I'm using the following code to create my dojo dijits:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"> 
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
    dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which browser?  Any idea what native string.js is?  How can we reproduce this?

Comment: I updated the post to reflect the problem more clearly. I have no idea what native string.js is; in the inspector, it says it is located at "chrome://devtools/native%20string.js", which is pretty puzzling to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a good solution for you, but this appears to be a bug in Chrome 4.0.249.89 on Windows (XP is what I've confirmed) and not related to their CDN hosted version of Dojo 1.4 (I run it locally).

Whatever the previous point release of Chome v4 was did not have this issue. I reported it as a bug via the Chrome bug report tool.

Also, FWIW, Chrome "5.0.322.2 dev" under Linux (Ubuntu 9.1) does not have this issue.

Comment: Oh, also, so far it appears to only be related to the use dijit.Dialog, though I haven't tested that theory thoroughly.

Comment: I've confirmed this problem in both the Google CDN, as well as a locally run copy. I'm running Windows 7, but not the Dev version. I might try switching to that channel to see how it works on windows.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this happening when processing very long strings?  I'm seeing an illegal access exception in Chrome when trying to JSON parse a string of over a thousand characters.